# "... is not public in org.bp.threeten.format.DateTimeFormatter" error when trying to turn String to LocalDate

Tags: java, android, time, localtime

I'm trying to turn a String into `LocalDate` using this code:

```
String end = sharedPref.getString("endDate", "Not available");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(end, formatter);
```

But it shows the error mentioned in the title. How do I fix it?
If there's a better way I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no constructor which took a format String, instead you have to call the static method [`ofPattern`](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern(java.lang.String)) like so :

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an explicit formatter at all in your case.

```
    LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(end);
```

Just drop the declaration of `formatter`. The format that you are trying to parse agrees with ISO 8601. `LocalDate` parses this format as its default, that is, without the formatter.

For the explanation of what went wrong, see the answer by YCF_L.

Link: [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).